# Which features identify an aircraft as a "Sixth Generation Fighter"?

Tags: fighter

I've been seeing all this news about how the Navy and Air force are going to get some new next gen fighter jets soon. However, I was wondering what will be the difference that makes it 6 gen instead of 5 gen. Will it be faster? More stealthy (if that's a word)? Or does nobody know? Thanks!

Comment: An extra 0 on the price tag.